# Installing anaconda3 offline

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

I want to learn python, hence a newbie.
i tried to install jupyter offline. I downloaded anaconda3 for windows, installed it, then ran the command conda install jupyter but nothing happened, perhaps it tries to go online for fetching some dependency files etc.
please guide me for offline installation of jupyter for python.
thanks in advance
maddy

Answer (score 0):

These comments are based on a windows 10 install. 
Are you sure Jupyter notebook did not install? Go to the command prompt and type "jupyter notebook" without the quotes. In my case that launched the notebook. If that doesn't work type "conda update jupyter" without the quotes and try launching the notebook again. If that doesn't work you may have to re-install Anaconda.
 As to launching the notebook offline simply use the command prompt and go to the directory/folder you want the notebook to launch in (for example I launch using a folder on a flash drive) and type "Jupyter Notebook" Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you download the anaconda installer jupyter is already included in the installer. So, in case you installed anaconda using the standard process you already have a working jupyter installation.

So, you should be able to start the jupyter notebook from a console writing:

```
jupyter notebook
```

and pressing [Enter].